# How does free hosting website work?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, asp-classic

Have you seen [Hostinghood](http://www.hostinghood.com) or some similar sites that a user can use a sub domain of the site and upload Html Css & .. to it! So I wonder how they work and how can I make this kinds of site .. This is my first question here and please instead of disliking ,reply to me cause I really need to know.. thanks!

Comment: Start by searching up nginx/apache and have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many aspects to do.

- **Subdomanis**

  First of all you must use a wildcard DNS record or you have to add a DNS record for each host. So It's better to use a wildcard record but It depends on your needs.
- **Storing files in separate private spaces**

  You must store files for each user in a specific directory.
- **Making a FileManager**

  You must make a control panel to let users access their own space and upload their files or delete, rename, move and copy them.
- **Accessing files via HTTP Request**

  Rewrite all request to a major file which can retrieve the subdomain name and get the corresponding directory. Attempt to access the requested file.

  For example : `http://mydomain.domain.com/css/style.css`

  Your script must access a directory like `/var/www/space/mydomain` and look there to find `css/style.css`.

  If the file exists print the contents and set correct headers. If the file does not exist show a `404 Not Found` page.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy some VPS install there a web server (apache, nginx), php parser and some database like mysql/mariadb or postgres, wrie your panel which handle the automatisation of creatong accounts, db users, vhosts, domains etc. Or you can buy and install some 3rd party panel like directadmin or cpanel. You should learn Unix first.